# Is it reasonable to require dialling international numbers?

Tags: work-environment, human-resources, company-policy

I'm managing IT support for a business that is in 40+ countries. We have a 24/7 service desk and provide numbers to reach it in several of our main countries but, for most other countries, with as few as three or four staff, we don't.

We frequently get users who have put international dialling blocks on their phone plans and or get upset at the cost.
We provide VOIP phone numbers for all employees and the Service Desk can, when requested, call users (if someone asks through Teams or by email).

HR is saying we should provide local numbers in every country but I feel they should be making a point to new employees that calling international numbers when working for an international business is not unreasonable and they should clarify the reimbursement policies.

Additionally, there are other departments (compliance, security, travel maangement and even HR) who don't provide local numbers.

**Is it reasonable to require employees to occasionally dial internationally?**

Comment: This is far too company specific for us to be able to give an answer.

Comment: Seems like this is a cost/benefit analysis by the company, and not a question we can answer here.

Comment: Am I understanding the question that there are employees at this company paying for the costs to make an international call? Why are these employees not using company phones?

Comment: It costs very little to set up a local number in another country which will forward to your IT service desk. There's really no good reason for you not to do this.

Comment: I should clarify, employees can optionally choose a company phone (for which we cover the bill) but overwhelmingly prefer to keep only their personal device and we also provide VOIP phones (for everyone, whether they have a physical device or not).
Additionally, we do reimburse expenses so the employee would be 'out' the expense for maximum ~10 days if they claimed it.

Comment: @brhans, it actually costs >$10k p.a. in some countries as you need legal entities and physical locations (where you don't necessarily need either to have employees).

Answer (score 4):

Your question makes it sound as if the employees are paying for these phone calls. If that is the case, and if you're asking if it's reasonable to require employees to occasionally dial internationally, the answer is no. It isn't reasonable to require employees to pay for the cost of company phone calls, local or international.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pure business question. You have cost A and cost B and your company has to decide which one they want to pay for. HR is not your boss. Let HR say whatever they want. If *your boss* says something about it, you will know what to do.

> Is it reasonable to require employees to occasionally dial internationally?

Absolutely. As long as it's a company phone. Dialing on their company phone during work times is part of their job. But to require anything of employees using their private phone is illegal in a few juristictions, if you are an international company you will probably have employees in a few of them.